# Need a "virtual FedEx" -- some way to transfer massive files cross-country

Tags: file-transfer, t1

My company has offices in NY and LA, and we spend a lot of money FedExing hard drives back and forth.

Is there some service that would allow us to save money by uploading the files at either end over a fast connection? Like 100 Mbps or more?

We don't need a 'dedicated' connection; we'd like to pay by the hour or GB.

Most of the files are 100-200 **giga**bytes.

FIOS would do the job; unfortunately, it's not available at either location.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Seems like I'm not making the problem clear -- we're not looking for a software solution; the bottleneck is our physical internet connections which max out at around 5mbps upstream.

We need some facility that will allow us to 'rent/lease' a high-speed (50 Mbps+) internet connection.

Sorry, maybe this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Hire interns with access to major university computer labs at each end...

Comment: Frankly, I suspect it's cheaper to just post the drives.  This is sort of the cost of doing business on opposite coasts (and is a reason small companies usually DON'T do business on opposite coasts)

Comment: _we spend a lot of money FedExing hard drives back and forth_. Reminds me of the old truism, **"Don't underestimate the bandwidth of a UPS Truck."** It often is the easiest way of moving huge amounts of traffic. Big pipes = Cubic Dollars. Renting/Leasing off site high speed still means you've got to get it there.

Comment: how would you get the data *to* your facility?

Comment: Is there any repetion of what you are transferring, it is it a new unique  100-200 Gb every time? Why is the peak rate so important that you want max transfer for only a little time each day? Some telcos may be able to provide a burst mode agreement

Comment: It's big old ProRes Quicktime files, uncompressible, unique. Maybe 2 or 3 times a week.

Comment: `maybe this is the wrong place to ask`.  You are probably right.  I think this fits in the shopping recommendation category of being off-topic on pretty much any stackexchange site.  If you are in LA and NY, maybe you could put host some equipment in a COLO somewhere.  Then just go plug a drive into the server at the co-location facility.  that isn't going to be cheap though.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend bittorent for this. If you upload your files to a tracker you can adjust download speed by adding more uploaders.

Comment: Not a solution ... the bottleneck is our upload connection speed.

Comment: @Dan: You can compress it before you share it with bittorrent.

Comment: These are video files, already compressed.

Answer (score 1):

To get a 100Mbps connection speed you need to talk to your ISP. I have AT&T and I currently have a 50Mbps line burstable to 100Mbps. So we can scale UP when we need to. This didn't come free, and we certainly had to talk to our AT&T rep to get this prepared ahead of time. The time it took AT&T to implement this was about 2-3weeks. Otherwise you can do what google does. Overnight Fedex external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

100-200MB shouldn't take very long to upload. I'd say at the very most, it wouldn't take more than a few hours, and that's much much faster than waiting for a physical thing to be shipped.

You could use a free service like http://www.dropbox.com/ or http://skydrive.live.com/

Comment: 100-200 GIGAbytes, not MB. Problem is not software, it's hardware.

Comment: Ah, makes a hell of a lot more sense lol.

Answer (score -1):

I would install rsync and run it almost continuously.
100GB takes 10000 seconds on 100Mbit i.e 3 hours - faster and cheaper than fedex

Comment: We do NOT HAVE 100mbps; more like 5! That's the point, where can I go to 'rent' a 100mbps connection?

Comment: Go buy it? Why you said you can have it? At one fedex shipping you can have T1 for a month or so...